# How to reuse named common HQL query in other named query in orm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using HQL named queries (which are defined in XML files) to query my database using Hibernate. Some of the queries are quite complex and I find myself copy-pasting substantial parts of one query to another, similar one.

I was wondering if it's possible at all to define common parts in a "named query fragment" and reuse that fragment across all my queries?

```
<named-native-query name="PeriodEntity.Retail.kpiQuery.NA.dly"
                        result-class="com.abc.data.store.insight.model.PeriodEntity">
        <query>
            SELECT
                LOCATION,
                MERCHANDISE,
                PERIOD,
                ATV,
                SALES,
                sales_ly,
                COMP,
                GM,
                GM_LY,
                AUR,
                AURLY,
                UNITSALES,
                UNITSALESLY,
                UNITS_COMP,
                UPT
            FROM
                dbo.V_DLY_API_PROC_RTL_MCLT_SLS_INV v
            WHERE
                LOC_BRD_ID = :brandId
                AND chnl_key = :channelId
            ORDER BY
                time_svc_lvl_opr_id ASC
      </query>
    </named-native-query>

<named-native-query name="PeriodEntity.Retail.kpiQuery.NA.dly"
                        result-class="com.abc.data.store.insight.model.PeriodEntity">
        <query>
            SELECT
                LOCATION,
                MERCHANDISE,
                PERIOD,
                ATV,
                SALES,
                sales_ly,
                COMP,
                GM,
                GM_LY,
                AUR,
                AURLY,
                UNITSALES,
                UNITSALESLY,
                UNITS_COMP,
                UPT
            FROM
                dbo.V_Week_API_PROC_RTL_MCLT_SLS_INV v
            WHERE
                LOC_BRD_ID = :brandId
                AND chnl_key = :channelId
            ORDER BY
                time_svc_lvl_opr_id ASC
      </query>
    </named-native-query>
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. If you want reusability, take a look at Criteria API or QueryDSL

Answer (score 0):

Since this is XML, you could use [XML entities](https://portswigger.net/web-security/xxe/xml-entities) for this purpose, but I doubt this will help readability. I'd just say, live with it. That's not necessarily duplication. IMO this is like saying that spelling `private final` for fields is duplication. It's not.